# The sum of my page ranks converge at 0.9

Tags: algorithm, web-crawler, pagerank

When I'm calculating page ranks of a set of crawled domains, using a dampening factor of 0.85. As mentioned in many page ranks papers, the sum of pageranks should converge to 1. But regardless of how many iterations I do, it seems to converge at 0.90xxx. If I lower dampening factor to 0.5, I move closer to 1 obviously.

Is it bad that the page ranks sum converge at 0.90, and what would this generally implicate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @RowlandShaw No. This is not about webmasters. It is about why an algorithm fails. The question itself is perfectly on topic. However, it is lacking details that are needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: OP: How did you handle 'sinks' (A node that has no outgoing links)?

Comment: @amit So where's the code? pang ranking is covered by the site aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @RowlandShaw As I said, the answer is lacking details, but is not off-topic ('unclear what you are asking' - perhaps). Look at [webmasters' FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), what suggests there that a question of "how to fix my pagerank?" should be on topic there? The OP does not mention even owning a webpage, for all we know, it could be some research he's doing about topography on the web, and is struggling with implementing the algorithms, and has nothing to do with being a webmaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became the algorithm:

```
// data structures

private HashMap<String, Double> pageRanks;
private HashMap<String, Double> oldRanks;
private HashMap<String, Integer> numberOutlinks;
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> inlinks;
private HashSet<String> domainsWithNoOutlinks;
private double N;

// data parsing occluded

public void startAlgorithm() {
    int maxIterations = 20;
    int itr = 0;
    double d = 0.85;
    double dp = 0;
    double dpp = (1 - d) / N;

    // initialize pagerank
    for (String s : oldRanks.keySet()) {
        oldRanks.put(s, 1.0 / N);
    }

    System.out.println("Starting page rank iterations..");
    while (maxIterations >= itr) {
        System.out.println("Iteration: " + itr);
        dp = 0;
        // teleport probability
        for (String domain : domainsWithNoOutlinks) {
            dp = dp + d * oldRanks.get(domain) / N;
        }
        for (String domain : oldRanks.keySet()) {
            pageRanks.put(domain, dp + dpp);

            for (String inlink : inlinks.get(domain).keySet()) { // for every inlink of domain
                pageRanks.put(domain, pageRanks.get(domain) + inlinks.get(domain).get(inlink) * d * oldRanks.get(inlink) / numberOutlinks.get(inlink));
            }
        }
        // update pageranks with new values
        for (String domain : pageRanks.keySet()) {
            oldRanks.put(domain, pageRanks.get(domain));
        }

        itr++;
    }
}
```

Where this line is the important one:

```
pageRanks.put(domain, pageRanks.get(domain) + inlinks.get(domain).get(inlink) * d * oldRanks.get(inlink) / numberOutlinks.get(inlink));
```

inlinks.get(domain).get(inlink) returns how much an inlink "like/referenced" the current domain, and we divide that by how many inlinks that current domain have. And "inlinks.get(domain).get(inlink)" is what I missed in my algorithm hence why the sum didn't converge at 1.

Read more: http://www.ccs.northeastern.edu/home/daikeshi/notes/PageRank.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is bad, since it indicate a bug in your implementation. Pagerank gives as a result a probability space, and it must sum to 1 as a basic sanity check.

My **guess** of the problem is **you did not handle 'sinks'** - nodes that have no outgoing links.

Common ways to handle sinks are:

1. For a sink vi, regard all nodes (vi,vj) as existing except vi=vj
2. remove them from the graph completely (and repeat until convergence)
3. Link them back to all nodes that linked to them (if vi is a sink, for all edge (vj,vi), add (vi,vj) as well).

Consider the following toy example: 2 pages, A,B. A links to B, B links to nothing. The resulting matrix is:

```
W=
    0      1
    0      0
```

Now, using d=0.85, you get the following equations:

```
v = 0.85* W'v + 0.15*[1/2,1/2]
v1 = 0.85* (0*v1+0*v2) + 0.15*1/2 = 0.15*1/2 = 0.075
v2 = 0.85*(1*v1 + 0*v2) + 0.15/2 = 0.85v1 + 0.075 = 0.006375 + 0.075 = 0.13875
```

And the sum is not 1.

However, if you handle the sinks, in one of the suggested approach (let's examine approach (1)), you will get:

```
W =
   0     1
   1     0
```

You will now get the set of equations:

```
v = 0.85* W'v + 0.15*[1/2,1/2]
v1 = 0.85* (0*v1+1*v2) + 0.15*1/2 = 0.85v2 + 0.075
v2 = 0.85*(1*v1 + 0*v2) + 0.15/2 = 0.85v1 + 0.075  (/0.85)-> 1/0.85 * v2 = v1 + 0.075/0.85
-> (add 2 equations)
1/0.85*v2 + v1 = 0.85v2 + 0.075 + v1 + 0.075/0.85 
-> (approximately)
0.326*v2 = 0.163
v2 = 0.5
```

As you can see, by using this method, we got a probability space and now, as expected, page rank of all nodes sum to 1.

Comment: What does W'v and "0.075  (/0.85)-> 1/0.85 * v2" mean?

Comment: @user2010496 W' is the transform of matrix W (W[i][j] == W'[j][i]), W'v is matrix multiply of W' and vector v. `(/0.85)->` means devide the equation on the left by 0.85 and get the equation on the right.

Comment: You're true, it's my sinks that are calculated wrong. I've implemented following an article, using "teleport probability", is that a viable option to handle sinks? http://pastebin.com/jbHAz9G6

Comment: Solved it, thanks for help, gonna write answer later. :)